# Angular 4 NgFor Completed Event

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

when `*ngFor` completed I want to call my custom function. (I'm using jQuery datatables for table. when tr elements completed I want to run this function `$('#myTable').dataTables(options);`

MyCode:

```
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let company of companies; let last = last;">
    <td>{{company.shortTitle}}</td>
    <td>{{company.shortAddress}}</td>
    <td>{{company.taxOffice}}</td>
    <td>{{company.taxNumber}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="company.eInvoice"><span class="label label-primary">Evet</span></td>
    <td *ngIf="!company.eInvoice"><span class="label label-danger">Hayır</span></td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I think that it is better to try searching for a module that could help you instead doing monkey stuff - check [**this**](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started) also [**this**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLoX1vkSMdU) could help

Answer (score 1):

Use `ngAfterViewInit` life-cycle hook for that. Since `*ngFor` is synchronous it will update DOM when `companies` changes and the added DOM nodes will be available in `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with either `ngAfterViewInit`

Code inside `ngAfterViewInit` will be executed after the view has been initialized

Your code will look like

```
export class className{
 .....
   ngAfterViewInit(){
      //code
   }
 .....
}
```

Comment: I didn't checked it. thout thank's for the info. will update now

Answer (score 0):

You should almost never mix Angular and jQuery. If you're doing, probably you will have problems or ugly code workarounds.

Angular handles the DOM to make everything work, the datatable (jQuery version) plugin too, so it's question of time to some conflict happen.

I suggest you the [ngx-datatables](http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/), but I'm pretty sure that you can find a bunch of simillar components. Also there are some [datatable wrapper](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/) for Angular 4.

Answer (score 0):

I'm solved this problem with https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started.
Thank you for this link @codtext